# Perl email failures

Tags: php, perl, email

I created a website to handle event registration with PHP mysqli etc. Upon completing the form on user submit it goes to a payment gateway. Upon payment, the gateway would send a confirmation to a perl page I had created.

In perl I would access the database, mark the registration as paid and send out a confirmation email. I was using MIME::Lite to send the email. My problem was that about 20% of receipt emails didn't seem to get sent...

Does anyone know why this might be? I wondered if it was due to a high volume of users entering payment all at the same time....

Is there a better way to send automatic emails? Should I store receipts in a DB then use something like cron to email batches?

The code I used for emailing was something like the following....

```
my $receipt = MIME::Lite->new(
To => $emailAddress,
Bcc  => 'admin@test.org.au',
From =>'admin@test.org.au',
Subject => 'registration',
Type =>'multipart/related'
);
$receipt->attach(Type => 'text/html',
Data => qq {
```

eventualy culminating with

```
$receipt->send();
```

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: have you seen a comment at the top of this module documentation? _"MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."_ (I suppose you are getting timeouts while connecting to SMTP server)

Comment: Have you inspected sendmail's  outgoing mail queue? (`mailq`)  Have you inspected sendmail's log files? [AFAIK MIME::Lite uses sendmail as default sending method]

Comment: Why do you implement part of the backend of your program in PHP and another part in Perl? Maintenance-wise it seems to make more sense to stick with one technology.

Comment: Huh. You know I never considered using PHP for all parts of the solution. That...makes sense. That's what I get for inheriting some code and not really questioning the status quo.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out that MIME::Lite isn't recommended. I'll make some changes.